# Is there a name for a lattice that is isomorphic to its dual?

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

If we have a lattice and we invert the order, we again obtain a lattice, called the dual lattice. Is there a name for a lattice that is isomorphic to its dual lattice?

Comment: Do you mean a self-dual lattice?

Comment: @Hagen I googled this before asking this question, and I found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered in a comment:

> Do you mean a self-dual lattice? –  Hagen von Eitzen Jan 1 '13 at 22:44

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_%28order_theory%29), the term 'self dual' applies to any partially ordered set equal to its own dual, regardless of whether it is a lattice.

(Note: there is a different meaning of 'lattice', resulting in another type of object called a 'self dual lattice'.)